# Using eventhandlers that are not in the current context

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

Is it possible to set, on a control (a linkbutton for example) an eventhandler which is not in the same context as the control creation?

For example, I have an instance of Class1 which instances Class2, the control is created in Class2, but I need the eventhandler to be in Class1.

Pseudo Code:

```
public class Class1
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Class2 MyClass2 = new Class2();
        MyClass2.DoSomething();
    }

    public void EventHandler()
    {
        // Handle the event
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        SomeControl control = new SomeControl();
        control.SomeEvent += parent.EventHandler;
    }
}
```

Regards
Moo

Comment: If you could elaborate a little more. Maybe give a more complete example of what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your Class2 expose a custom public event.  This event is triggered when the control event fires.

```
// In Class2

    public event EventHandler<EventArgs<T>> ControlClickedEvent = null;

    protected void OnControlClickedEvent()
    {
        if (ControlClickedEvent != null)
        {
            ControlClickedEvent(this, new EventArgs());  
        }
    }

  ...

   private void cmdButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        OnControlClickedEvent();
   }
```

Then have your Class1 subscribe to that event.  The "event handler" is part of Class1.

```
// In Class1
MyClass2.ControlClickedEvent += new EventHandler<EventArgs<ControlClickedEvent>>(EventHandler);
```

If you are using multiple threads, ensure you use the InvokeRequired and BeginInvoke / Invoke methods in the code of the eventhandler in Class1.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying darin's code:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public Class1()
    {
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
        class2.Control.SomeEvent += this.EventHandler;
    }

    public EventHandler()
    {
        //DoStuff
    }
}

public class Class2
{
    public Control control;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class1 
{
    public Class1()
    {
        new Class2().CreateControl(EventHandler);
    }

    public void EventHandler() {}
}

public class Class2
{
    public void CreateControl(Action eventHandler)
    {
        SomeControl control = new SomeControl();
        control.SomeEvent += eventHandler;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, i think he wants it the other way around, Control in Class2 & EventHandler in Class1.

Comment: Ahh, close but not what I am after.  Class 1 will instantiate Class 2 so Class 2 is a child of Class 1, and call a method on the Class 2 instance which will create the controls.  However, I then somehow need to set the control eventhandler in Class 2 to the eventhandler method in the parent Class 1.

Comment: Modified my sample accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I have fallen out of favor of using straight events in C# these days for most communication like this.  I prefer a more decoupled communication pattern, like the "[Event Aggregator](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html)" which has many benefits over traditional event hooking.  They include:

- Reduced coupling (Class1 and Class2
  don't need to know about each other)
- Reduced event storms
- Weak hookups (no memory leaks if you
  forget to disconnect)
- Filtering